# iOS app Submit response - we are not able to continue because we need additional

Tags: ios, app-store, submit, app-store-connect

I have developed some iOS app but this is the first app which I want to upload to app store. Demo username and password has been given but now new message from Resolution Center on iTunes Connect is -

**"Hello, Thank you for your response. We have started the review of your app, but we are not able to continue because we need additional"**

Here what is the meaning of 'additional'? 
Do I have to give all API parameters data ?

I asked this question to to Resolution Center on iTunes Connect. They answered me same statement.

Answer (score 0):

There is a section named "Notes". Please mention additional information there.
Such as, how to login, how the app works, how to test the app etc. May be they are not sure about the app flow/features.